# Array is getting updated as values are change

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I am trying to figure why my array is getting updated dynamically?

I have the following class

```
class LocationData {
   var address: String = ""
   var city: String = ""
   var deviceName: String = ""
   var deviceId: String = ""
   var state: String = ""
}
```

then I have the following function

```
func fetchLocationItems(sortByKey1: String, sortByKey2: String, deviceID: String, isAsecending: Bool) -> [LocationData]{

    var locationObjectArray = [LocationData]()

    var locationData = LocationData()
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Location")
        let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: sortByKey1, ascending: isAsecending)
        let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: sortByKey2, ascending: isAsecending)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]
        let results = try locationContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
        var count = 0
        if results.count > 0 {
            for item in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                if item.valueForKey("deviceID")  as! String == deviceID {
                   locationData.deviceId  = item.valueForKey("deviceID")  as! String  
                   locationData.address = item.valueForKey("address") as! String
                   locationData.city = item.valueForKey("city") as! String
                   locationData.state = item.valueForKey("state") as! String
                   locationData.deviceName = item.valueForKey("deviceName") as! String
                   locationObjectArray.insert(locationData, atIndex: count)
                   count++
                }
             }
            //try context.save()
        }

    } catch {
        print("There was error getting data")
    }
    return locationObjectArray

}
```

So I have 4 records in coredata. First time through the "for item loop", locationDate get inserted into locationObjectArry

second time through the loop, the values in locationObjectArray at index 0 get update with the new values of for example

```
locationData.deviceId  = item.valueForKey("deviceID")  as! String  
locationData.address = item.valueForKey("address") as! String
```

and so on.

So at the end of the loop, the values of locationObjectArray[0..4] are all the same as the last record.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because Your object is not init new in each loop. So object still the same

try:

```
for item in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
    if item.valueForKey("deviceID")  as! String == deviceID {
        // init new LocationData
        var locationData = LocationData()
        locationData.deviceId  = item.valueForKey("deviceID")  as! String
        locationData.address = item.valueForKey("address") as! String
        locationData.city = item.valueForKey("city") as! String
        locationData.state = item.valueForKey("state") as! String
        locationData.deviceName = item.valueForKey("deviceName") as! String
        locationObjectArray.insert(locationData, atIndex: count)
        count++
    }
}
```